# Google sheet key

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The ROW function in Google sheet gives the row number and Column function gives the column number, is there any function which can give the sheet URL in a cell or the sheet key in a cell.

I know URL or key can be copied from the top, but is there any function to get the sheet URL or key in a cell?

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution**

Upon double checking, there's no dedicated function available on the [Google Sheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273) to get the Google Sheet ID/key. But you can refer to this sample [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#:%7E:text=are%20bound%20to.-,Creating%20a%20bound%20script,find%20or%20open%20the%20script.) below by using the  [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl) method to get the sheet URL and then only return the Sheet ID from the full sheet URL:

**Script:**

```
function sheetID(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var resourceUrl = ss.getUrl();
  var result = /\/([\w-_]{15,})\/(.*?gid=(\d+))?/.exec(resourceUrl);
  return result[1];
}
```

Here's the reference [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717596/15384825) I've used to get only the Sheet ID on the URL.

**Result**

After putting the `=sheetID()` custom script on a cell, it will show the Sheet ID, as seen here:

[image]